# Dropdown inside the second last column of each row except the first one in the last cell not working

Tags: html

Below is the code

I will try to ask this question again later on

Comment: IDs have to be unique within a document, yours are not

Comment: [ID's Must Be Unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme), specifically because it will cause problems in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) and CSS when you try to interact with those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your text input fields all have the same ID, so when you're getting the value, it just grabs the value from the first element with that ID. IDs should only exist once per HTML document.

Comment: You have to be a bit more specific than that. Your update did not help clarify things, you only showed one row, and it still had the same IDs, and you were still targeting those same IDs in your JavaScript file